# setting cudaDeviceProperty: cudaKernelExecTimeoutEnabled

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to set the device property `cudaKernelExecTimeoutEnabled` to 0 at runtime? Currently it is 1 because I'm also running an X-server on it. The problem is, that my threads time out.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can disable the timeout (about 6 to 7 seconds for me) by adding an option to your X11 configuration. On modern Linux systems, there is no X11 configuration any more, everything is autodetected, but you can create it manually:

```
mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

Then add the following into this file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "My GPU"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    Option      "Interactive" "0"
EndSection
```

The key here is the "Interactive" option. This works for me even without X11 restart. It was obvious that this configuration is read and applied as soon as my OpenCL application is started.

"Identifier" can be an arbitrary value. "Driver" is "nvidia" in my case, since I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver for Linux (part of the official Debian package repositories).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are on windows:

You need to disable the windows driver timeout:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Watchdog\Display\DisableBugCheck
```

create a REG_DWORD and set it to 1.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm on linux ubuntu 10.10, and I run an nVidia Quadro FX 570.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you need to use the `nvidia-smi` command to change properties of the device. But I think if you're running a display on the GPU, you might not be able to set that property.