# Disable Nvidia OpenCL kernel watchdog on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencl, nvidia, watchdog

By querying the device, I see

*Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes*

I want to disable this feature, what should I do ?

I am running with a Tesla on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/OS tech support.

Comment: As someone searching 7 years later for an answer to this question, comments like Marc's make me wish there was a downvote button on comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these questions.

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833261/how-to-disable-or-change-the-timeout-limit-for-the-gpu-under-linux) lists an Xorg config that might disable it in general.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331140/setting-cudadeviceproperty-cudakernelexectimeoutenabled).
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695807/opencl-timeout-on-beignet-doesnt-raise-error) is for Beignet on Intel, but perhaps the NVidia driver has some equivalent `enable_hangcheck`.  I'd favor the previous bullet if it works.